# DOM element selection by id with special symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to figure out how to select a DOM element by it's Id, where the id is something ugly. Here is an example of an id:

```
<element id='[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]'>
```

At some point from the back-end I am receiving unknown for me id name and I have to find the DOM element with that ID.

I have tryed using jQuery like:

```
$('#' + elementId) //where the elementId is a string from the example above
```

but jQuery returns:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]
```

I have also tryed to use the document selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#' + elementId) //with the id from above
```

again resulting in error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]' is not a valid selector.
```

**[My Question]**
Is there a way to force these selectors (or any other suggested by you selector) not to treath the selector argument as expression? Is there a way to make such a selection?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I might be wrong (but it's worth a try)...`[]` is for an array which might be the reason it's not working. Try to just use letters, hyphens and underscores for your ID's. There are probably others you can use but it just keeps things simple this way.

Comment: You are using meta-character look into http://alexandregiannini.blogspot.in/2011/05/escaping-strings-for-jquery-selectors.html to escape them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select it like this (assume element is div)

```
$('div[id="[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]"]')....;
```

Or

```
var id = '[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]"]';
$('div[id="' + id + '"]')....;
```

Comment: @putvande Of course it will. See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pRV7H/). I assume that was your down vote.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke it seems this might do the tick m8, thanks a lot for the help, but I still have a problem. Can you please tell me how to use the same approach when "[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]" is a variable. For example - var searchId = "[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]". In this case $('div[id=' + searchId + ']') is not working because it appends my string without the quatations. Can you please edit your answer with the case when the searchId is a variable. Thanks!

Comment: Your were just missing some quotation marks (just after _equal sign_ and just before closing _square bracket_) See updated answer.

Comment: I see, but my problem is that I am not the one that is writting the string in the code. The string comes from my back-end and I have just the searchId variable with it's appropriate value at that point. I cannot do 'searchId' for obvious reasons. How can I make the quatation on the variable to make your example work? Thanks again for the time!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The _quotation marks_ go in the selector, not the variable (see edit). If you know that the value of `searchId` is `'[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]'` then `$('div[id="' + searchId + '"]')` will find the div ( or `$('*[id="' + searchId + '"]')` to find any element with with that id)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I see your point. But in this case it is not working. THe value ot searchId is "[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]". I am trying to select with $('div[id="' + searchId + '"]') and $("div[id='" + searchId + "']") but it returns [] in both cases. While $('div[id="[$something:else#52,$someth:else#51]"]') still results in the desired DOM element.

Comment: I cant spot the difference. You can see that it works with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRV7H/1/). Is by any chance searchId JSON format?